# AFNetworking и пробелы в запросе

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, afnetworking

Как заставить AFNetworking, чтобы уходил запрос на адрес вида

`URLPath = "http://site.ru/script.php?text=bla bla bla"`

(текст с пробелами - отзыв с последующей вставкой его в MySQL)?

Отправляю так:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager * manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:URLPath parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

 }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
 }];
```

Когда URLPath содержит пробелы, то крашится:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: URLString'
```

Если без пробелов - все хорошо.

ps. На яве уходило все с пробелами без проблем.

В голову пришла лишь пока одна мысль - заменять в коде пробелы определенной комбинацией символов. А на сервере, перед в ставкой в таблицу, регуляркой снова менять эту комбинацию на пробелы... или же есть более элегантное решение непосредственно в самом коде на клиентской части?

Comment: Я думаю, что Вашу проблему решили вот тут: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13974217/3868736

Answer (score 1):

Думаю следует изменить способ формирования адреса, или всего запроса в целом:

1. Лучше всего использовать встроенные и отлаженные механизмы библиотеки (AFNetworking):

   ```
   NSString *serviceEndpoint = @"http://site.ru/script.php";
   NSDictionary *params = @{@"text": @"bla bla bla, ту ту ту"};

   AFHTTPRequestOperationManager * manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
   [manager GET:serviceEndpoint parameters:params
       success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
           NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
       }
       failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
           NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
       }];
   ```
2. Если вдруг этот механизм чем-то радикально не подходит, то лучше формировать строковое представление запроса, кодируя параметры до подстановки в общую строку, с соответствующим набором разрешенных символов:

   ```
   NSString* textValue = @"bla bla bla, ту ту ту";
   NSString* urlPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://site.ru/script.php?text=%@", [textValue stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]]];
   ```